# Is this joint probability or conditional probability?

Tags: bayesian, conditional-probability, joint-distribution

Recently I've been studying Bayesian statistics. Often when I see this 
$$p(y|x, \theta)$$
I treated as a probability of y given x and $\theta$. This made 
sense when solving linear regression since $\theta$ was a fixed value/vector. 
I think it's also written this way:
$$p(y|x; \theta)$$
But with Bayesian, $\theta$ becomes a probability distribution. 
Does that make 
$$p(y|x, \theta)$$
a joint distribution?

EDIT: (context)
In Bayesian linear regression, 
$$y = \theta^Tx + \epsilon$$
and
$$P(y|x, \theta) = {1 \over \sqrt{2\pi}\sigma} exp(-(y-\theta^Tx)^2 / 2\sigma^2)$$
where 
$$\theta \tilde{} N(0, \tau^2I)$$

Comment: Probably still a conditional density, but hard to be certain without seeing the context

Answer (score 1):

> with Bayesian, θ becomes a probability distribution.

This is incorrect: in Bayesian statistics, $\theta$ is treated *as* a random variable and associated *with* a probability distribution, with density $\pi(\theta)$ say, and the distribution of the data is then considered as a conditional density given $\theta$.

> I treated as a probability of y given x and θ

This is unclear as *given* has a probabilistic meaning, signifying *conditional on*, as well as a vernacular one, meaning *provided with*. The only setting when $p(y|x, \theta)$ can be treated as a conditional probability density is the Bayesian framework.